# Does .NET have built-in functions mapping between character entities and their unicode values?

Tags: c#, .net, unicode, f#, character-entities

```
& Eacute ;  \u00C9
& egrave ;  \u00E8
& eacute ;  \u00E9
& apos   ;  \u0027
```

something like:

```
f("&apos;") = '\u0027' where f :: string -> char
g('\u0027') = "&apos;" where g :: char -> string
```

Or is there a third-party library with a BSD or MIT style permissive free license with something of this sort? Otherwise I'll have to create my own mapping but it's quite urgent and I don't want to miss out on available functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [SecurityElement.Escape method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securityelement.escape.aspx) to go from unicode to character entity:

```
char c = '\u0027';
string entity = System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape(c.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(entity);
```

As for going in reverse, I think you're out of luck and will need to write your own approach.

EDIT: you might also find the [HttpUtility.HtmlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73z22y6h.aspx) and [HttpUtility.HtmlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k.aspx) methods useful. To use them you'll need to add a reference to System.Web.

Comment: thx! this function could be used to automatize creating a mapping in the opposite direction. :)

Comment: puhaa ... thx once again for htmlencode and htmldecode *^o^*!!

Comment: @Cetin no prob! Glad those helped :)